# How to remove this resume palavers-chaves as shown in the image before abstract

Tags: keywords

```
\documentclass[10pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{infocomp}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[sort,compress]{cite}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I have answered your question because I searched for 'conexões ifce' and I found the Overleaf template. That was a bit lucky, for your next question it would be better if you would specify where you found the code that you are using. Also, in general it is better to post a complete but minimal example, meaning an example that can be compiled and shows the problem and nothing else. Your code did not meet these requirements: it could not be compiled (it shows only a list of packages) and it is not minimal, because it contains many packages that are not related to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the file `infocomp.sty` the formatting of the title and related elements is defined, specifically in the `\@maketitle` command starting from line 77. You can comment the Portuguese parts out to remove them from the output.

Code:

```
\def\@maketitle{\newpage
 \null
 \begin{center}
   \vglue -6pt
  {\Large\textsf{\textbf{\@title}}\par}
   \vglue 12pt plus 6pt minus 3pt
  {\normalsize\sc
   \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author\end{tabular}\par}
   \vglue 12pt plus 6pt minus 3pt
  {\normalsize
   \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@address\end{tabular}\par}
   \vglue 18pt plus 12pt minus 6pt
 %  \vspace{1cm}
%  {\Large\textsf{\textbf{\@englishtitle}}\par}
% comment this line if the article does not have an abstract in English
%   {\quotation\noindent{\bf Resumo. }\@resumo\endquotation} % COMMENT THIS LINE
%      {\quotation\noindent{\bf Palavras-chaves: }\@palchaves\endquotation} % AND THIS LINE
  {\quotation\noindent{\bf Abstract. }\@abstract\endquotation}

% comment this line if the article does not have keywords in English
   {\quotation\noindent{\bf Keywords: }\@keywords\endquotation}
%   \vspace{1cm}(Received \@receivedate~ / Accepted \@acceptdate)
   \end{center}\par
\vskip 12pt}
```

Result:

[image]